# mysqli->query returns true on update, but no rows affected

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

I am experiencing some issues when trying to update rows in mysql.

I've tried to print the query and run it in my sql client, and it updates the rows as expected.

This line:

> $this->mysqli->query($query);

Returns bool (true) as expected, and is correct according to the php documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

```
public function query($query, $parameters = array()) {
    if ((is_array($parameters) && count($parameters) > 0) || (is_string($parameters) && !empty($parameters))) {
        $this->lastPrepared = true;

        if ($this->prepare($query) === false)
            return false;

        $this->bind((is_array($parameters) ? $parameters : array($parameters)));
        if ($this->execute() === false)
            return false;
    } else {
        $this->lastPrepared = false;

        if (!$this->stmt = $this->mysqli->query($query)) {
            debug('Query failed: (' . $this->mysqli->errno . ') ' . $this->mysqli->error);
            return false;
        }
    }

    return $this->stmt;
}
```

I have searched around, and found questions similar to my question, but non of the answers have helped me found a solution.

EDIT: Okay, so I can see now that $this->mysqli->affected_rows; returns -1, which means that there is an error. However, mysqli->errno and mysqli->error are empty.

The query I am trying to run is:

> UPDATE payments_scheduled SET active = 0 WHERE id=1 OR id=2

Columns:

id - type: int - length: 10 - extra: unsigned, pk

active - type: tinyint - length: 1 - extra: unsigned

Comment: i don't see the query .. could be  your query work right but don't match rows..

Comment: But if I type var_dump($query); in the query function and copy that query and paste it in my sql client, it works just fine. So the source to the problem must be within the function above?

Comment: show the query .. is better ..

Comment: all the column type are number ?

Comment: Updated my question, look at the bottom to see info about query and columns.

Comment: It is' strange query is right and the execution returns true (1) ... check better ..

Comment: Would love to check better, but don't know what to check :p Mysqli doesn't return any errors, all responses are as expected, except for affected_rows which returns -1 indicating an error. However, I have no clue what the error is and where to find it.

Comment: is the table looked  by some IDE action ?  .. try exit the IDE  and reopen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found the problem.

I was starting a transaction within a method, and I never comitted.

My apologies for wasting your time, you could not have figured out the problem by looking at the code I provided. I was sure the issue was within that query method (but I was wrong).

I'll vote up each and everyone of you that tried to help out.

Comment: Thank you, it was actually this comment that helped me...

Answer (score 3):

Updating 0 rows does not count as a failure, it simply means there were no rows to update based on the selection criteria. In many cases this would be expected behaviour and thus returns true.

Comment: I am trying to update 2 rows, and when I copy the query it works fine in my sql client. And affected rows gave me -1 not 0.

Comment: Isn't  $this your mysqli object? So instead of $this->mysqli->errno and similar just do $this->errno?

Comment: And above that $this->query

Comment: No, $this is my class (in my case DBWrapper) it has a private variable called $mysqli. In the constructor of the class I instantiate a mysqli object. Like this: $this->mysqli = new mysqli(.....

Comment: in `if (!$this->stmt = $this->mysqli->query($query))` you have a single =. Are you sure that is doing what you want it to?

Comment: Yes, I want to store the result, not do an equals check.